# Solr DataImportHandler - JOIN vs. separate entity

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

In Solr DIH data-config.xml, is it better to fetch as many fields as possible with the query in the main entity with JOIN like:

```
<entity name="Lists" 
        pk="l.list_id" 
        query="SELECT l.list_id AS id, l.user_id, lo.is_votable FROM lists l
                 INNER JOIN list_options lo ON lo.list_id = l.list_id">
```

or use a separate sub-entity like:

```
<entity name="Lists" 
        pk="l.list_id" 
        query="SELECT l.list_id AS id, l.user_id FROM lists l">

  <entity name="ListOptions" 
          query="SELECT lo.is_votable FROM list_options lo 
                   WHERE lo.list_id=${Lists.id}" />

</entity>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Few Pointers that may help you to decide :-

- Sub entities fire a query for each of the records and hence would be slower in performance if you have a huge collection.
- If you have a one to one mapping you can use the join so that you get all the fields with one query itself.
- If you have multiple records for the root you would use the sub entity which would probably create a multivalued field. (You cant use a single join query as it would return multiple rows for the same document unless you want the behavior)

Comment: Yes. I confirmed it by testing. I kept one entity per table. Had the main query plus 11 queries in sub-entities. Each entity opened a separate client connection to the DB. Once I moved 7 of the sub-entity queries to the main query with JOINs (one-to-one), it gave a 3-fold improvement in indexing speed.

Comment: The sub entities feature is almost useless due to slowness.